# Gnome crashes after resuming from idle screensaver or suspend

Tags: gnome, suspend, screensaver, 18.10

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome.
Sometimes, all two or three days, Gnome crashes after resuming from idle screensaver or suspend. I manually have to press "Strg + Alt + F1" and login again to be able to continue because I only see a purple screen. The last output of  `journalctl -b /usr/bin/gnome-shell` is

```
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a0fb60' has no handler with id '215849'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a0fb60' has no handler with id '215850'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a73350' has no handler with id '215851'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a73350' has no handler with id '215852'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a72b90' has no handler with id '215853'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a72b90' has no handler with id '215854'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192b44440' has no handler with id '215855'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192b44440' has no handler with id '215856'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287b340' has no handler with id '215857'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287b340' has no handler with id '215858'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a723d0' has no handler with id '215861'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a723d0' has no handler with id '215862'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287a3c0' has no handler with id '215863'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287a3c0' has no handler with id '215864'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287ab80' has no handler with id '215865'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287ab80' has no handler with id '215866'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287bb00' has no handler with id '215867'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e19287bb00' has no handler with id '215868'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192b44c00' has no handler with id '215869'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192b44c00' has no handler with id '215870'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192b453c0' has no handler with id '215871'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192b453c0' has no handler with id '215872'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e1929af3f0' has no handler with id '215875'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e1929af3f0' has no handler with id '215876'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e1929afbb0' has no handler with id '215877'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e1929afbb0' has no handler with id '215878'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a0e420' has no handler with id '215879'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2641: instance '0x55e192a0e420' has no handler with id '215880'
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[6953]: Object Meta.WindowActor (0x55e192a0ebe0), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from 
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e19092c210 ==
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #0   7fff6ed0b640 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/GObject.js:468 (7f8be5bcc040 @ 25)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #1   7fff6ed0b6e0 b   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/theming.js:416 (7f8bb2e65040 @ 20)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #2   7fff6ed0b7d0 b   self-hosted:261 (7f8be5bc1dc0 @ 223)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #3   7fff6ed0b890 b   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/theming.js:415 (7f8bb2e60f70 @ 172)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #4   7fff6ed0c510 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #5   55e198282308 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/theming.js:424 (7f8bb2e650d0 @ 17)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #6   7fff6ed0d480 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #7   55e198282288 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/theming.js:89 (7f8bb2e60790 @ 42)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #8   7fff6ed0e3f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #9   55e198282200 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:456 (7f8bb2e565e0 @ 82)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #10   7fff6ed0f360 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #11   55e198282168 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:1784 (7f8bb2e5c9d0 @ 116)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #12   7fff6ed102d0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #13   55e1982820e8 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/docking.js:1903 (7f8bb2e5cdc0 @ 37)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #14   7fff6ed11240 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #15   55e198282068 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/extension.js:31 (7f8bb2e4ad30 @ 12)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #16   55e198281fa8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:83 (7f8be585a040 @ 436)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #17   55e198281f28 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:354 (7f8be585ab80 @ 13)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #18   7fff6ed123b0 b   self-hosted:261 (7f8be5bc1dc0 @ 223)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #19   55e198281ea8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:353 (7f8be585aaf0 @ 64)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #20   55e198281e28 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:371 (7f8be585ac10 @ 87)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #21   7fff6ed134f0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (7f8be5bc18b0 @ 386)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #22   7fff6ed14340 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:208 (7f8be5541ca0 @ 254)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #23   7fff6ed14fc0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #24   55e198281c10 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:177 (7f8be5541af0 @ 100)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #25   7fff6ed15f40 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #26   55e198281b68 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:1210 (7f8be55288b0 @ 105)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #27   55e198281ac0 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #28   55e198281a40 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:1200 (7f8be5528790 @ 73)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #29   55e198281998 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #30   55e198281908 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:627 (7f8be5527040 @ 83)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #31   55e198281860 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #32   55e1982817a8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:687 (7f8be55271f0 @ 415)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #33   55e198281700 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (7f8be5bb0b80 @ 71)
Nov 10 17:05:42 XPS-9370 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[6953]: #34   55e198281640 i   self-hosted:979 (7f8be5bf01f0 @ 440)
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: g_dir_open_with_errno: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: g_filename_to_utf8: assertion 'opsysstring != NULL' failed
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: g_dir_open_with_errno: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: g_filename_to_utf8: assertion 'opsysstring != NULL' failed
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill (g-io-error-quark, 36)
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Nov 10 17:05:58 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js 1564]: reference to undefined property "MetaWindowXwayland"
Nov 10 17:06:12 XPS-9370 gnome-shell[7295]: Connection to xwayland lost
```

Can someone help?

Edit 1:
I think I see connection with the connecting/disconnecting of an external monitor. At least, this seems to make the problem appear more often.

Edit 2:
`sudo blkid` returns

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="4ac6dcee-933c-449a-983f-b0ede0f24c5d" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="15E7-DD98" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="1d435577-b51a-4491-b78e-b33b18783cfc"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="OS" UUID="15F8-5108" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="fat32" PARTUUID="266e101c-75bc-4d67-82b4-33dfda5d4cf6"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="7ea246ac-cdde-4c3f-acc0-40ab63d8dd47" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4bd55ae7-f76f-4c8e-a8fd-3dd795e29eef"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="71013368-e9f9-4063-b176-fd9d4a73e524" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="bf879d7d-66cf-419d-99a6-e09b192cd5eb"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="aef0d414-56c5-44ba-9dd2-55935e35b816" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e9b8805d-c543-4abd-935d-2a5cff34968c"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
```

`cat /etc/fstab` returns

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

UUID=7ea246ac-cdde-4c3f-acc0-40ab63d8dd47   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
UUID=15E7-DD98  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0   1
UUID=71013368-e9f9-4063-b176-fd9d4a73e524   none    swap    sw  0   #0
UUID=aef0d414-56c5-44ba-9dd2-55935e35b816   /home   ext4    defaults 0  2
```

`cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` returns

```
RESUME=UUID=71013368-e9f9-4063-b176-fd9d4a73e524
```

and `free -h` returns

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       6,3Gi       4,3Gi       1,1Gi       4,7Gi       7,6Gi
Swap:          31Gi        11Mi        31Gi
```

Comment: Do you have any GNOME shell extensions installed? Edit your question with `ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Yes, but it also crashes with all extensions disabled.

Comment: Edit your question to include `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and `free -h`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Thank's for your help! I edited the question as you requested.

Comment: Minor nit... in /etc/fstab, change `UUID=71013368-e9f9-4063-b176-fd9d4a73e524   none    swap    sw  0   #0` to `UUID=71013368-e9f9-4063-b176-fd9d4a73e524   none    swap    sw  0   0`. Also, run `memtest` from the GRUB menu, or a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, for at least one complete pass. Report back.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that must have happend during copying it in this thread.
I already ran memtest and it didn't find anything.

Comment: Try changing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, change `#WaylandEnable=false` to `WaylandEnable=false`, reboot. See if there's any change. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem: It was the preinstalled Dash-To-Dock extension.
Completely disabling it via

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
sudo mv ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com{,.bak}
```

fixed it.